# wordpress plugin that show my reputation (points) in any stackexchange project in my wordpress blogs

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, author, list-authors, stackoverflow

I'm seeking for a plugin show my points (reputation)  of Stackexchange (not Stackoverflow) in my Wordpress blogs.

or other projects in stackexchange like :

1. Superuser
2. Security
3. Serverfault
4. SharePoint

or author plugin that show points like Google plus beside the picture of every authors.

or help me about "how can i develop a plugin do this for me? or show my profiles in stackexchange's projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a plugin but the easiest way is to just embed your stack flair: https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair

For a more detialed  solution I recommend you just fetch the Stack API using the the WordPress HTTP API, the docs are here: http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API

The Stack API is very easy to work with and returns JSON. For you reputation for example you would query this url, you can change the site paramater to the ones you want: http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users?order=desc&sort=reputation&inname=saber%20tabatabaee%20yazdi&site=stackoverflow

so you would have something like this in your plugin:

```
$stackProfile = 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users?order=desc&sort=reputation&inname=saber%20tabatabaee%20yazdi&site=stackoverflow';
$stackAPI = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get($stackProfile) );
//your output
```

The Stack paramaters you can query are here: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs